# Custom PieProgress in android

Tags: android, progress-bar, custom-view

Hi i want to draw a PieProgress like an attached image.

[image]

Any Suggestion ?

I can draw this Progress but how can i place this parallel image on the center of this progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

what is the problem here?
draw image in center:

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_drawable);
d.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
d.draw(canvas);
```

user `drawArc` for progress, draw one with 360 degrees and another according progress with smaller thickness over it with black color and one more for left space with white color.

or draw two with different radius with black color and then one more with proper angle that will show progress, also with black color or whatever.